# Physical significance of argument principle.

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, differential-forms, visualization, motivation

I have studied complex analysis in which there is a milestone theorem called argument principle.It states that if $\Omega\subset \mathbb C$ is an open connected set and $f$ be a meromorphic function on $\Omega$,and $C$ be a simple closed contour lying inside $\Omega$ with its interior contained in $\Omega$,and no poles and zeros on $C$,then $\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\pi i(N_0-N_\infty)$,where $N_0$ and $N_\infty$ are respectively the number of zeros and poles counting multiplicity of $f$ inside $C$.

[image]

I understand the statement but I actually want to feel the theorem.I have seen some books regarding $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ as the differential change $d\log f(z)$ in the value of logarithm and then they say that $\log(f(z))=\ln|f(z)|+i\text{arg}(f(z))$,so change in logarithm is essentially change in argument because the end point and beginning point are same resulting in constant modulus,so$\int_C d\log(f(z))$ corresponds to the change in argument of $f(z)$ when we move along $C$.I cannot understand why it is so.Can someone provide me some motivation for this?I do not want rigorous understanding because that will require differential forms which is too advanced for me,what I want is the main intuition.Also I need to clarify that I do not know anything about winding numbers.

Comment: I feel like your question contains an intuitive explanation already (by explaining how log breaks down in terms of the argument, etc.), which means I don't understand what you're asking about. Are you saying you don't understand why the changes in $\ln|z|$ cancel out in the integral? That you don't understand why the changes on the argument don't? Something else?

Comment: @MarkS. I do not understand why when we move around $C$ keeping a zero $z_0$(say) in its interior, the corresponding image moves around $0$ keeping $0$ in its interior.Why it is so that a closed curve maps to another closed curve and interior goes to interior,it could have been so that $z_0$ is inside $C$ but $f(z_0)=0$ is outside $f(C)$ so when we move one round about $C$ we move in the image through $f(C)$ one round but $0$ is outside,so argument does not change.